# How to move an image within a button?

Tags: html, css, image, button

I'm pretty new to css. I figured out how to put an image in a button and how to use padding to move it around within the rectangle of the button. But as I stared adding more buttons to my page the padding on each button changed. I think this is because I need some sort of but once I started using divs I messed up the padding somehow and I can't figure out how to fix it. I tried centering (using top percentage and translate) the image within the button as well but it just moves the whole button. I need a way to make each picture on each button on my page to be centered or at least have padding so I can center it on my own for each individual image.

[Here's a picture of some of my buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcTOB.png)
The button on bottom is exactly how I want it, but the button on top is not centered since the image is a different size. But when I change the code of one the other button changes as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale =1">
<style>
    .button {
        background-color: #FFC627;
        border: none};
        border-radius: 20px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .roles-and-responsibilities {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    .button:hover {background-color: #5C6670}
    .buttoniactive {
        background-color: #5C66703
        transform: translateY (4px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "roles-and-responsibilities">
```

Comment: Could you also give a picture of the buttons, both the ones behaving and the ones misbehaving?

Comment: Please edit your question and post your HTML and CSS as code instead of a link to an image.